# ecryptfs-recover-private creating unreadable encrypted folders

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, data-recovery

After months of proper functioning `ecryptfs` has become corrupted and rendered `/home/` inaccessible. When running (both via guest account and from live-CD):

```
root@ubuntu:/media/backup/home/me# ecryptfs-mount-private
ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly`
```

I then tried:

```
root@ubuntu:/media/backup/home/me# ecryptfs-recover-private
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Found [/media/backup/home/.ecryptfs/me/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: Y
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] n
INFO: To recover this directory, you MUST have your original MOUNT passphrase.
INFO: When you first setup your encrypted private directory, you were told to record
INFO: your MOUNT passphrase.
INFO: It should be 32 characters long, consisting of [0-9] and [a-f].

Enter your MOUNT passphrase: 
INFO: Success!  Private data mounted read-only at [/tmp/ecryptfs.uDWfDMCO].
root@ubuntu:/media/backup/home/me# ls /tmp/ecryptfs.uDWfDMCO/ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.F
Display all 124 possibilities? (y or n)'
```

This created 124 encrypted folders which apparently hold my `/home/` data. I just don't know how to access this data. Moreover, looking at `/var/log/syslog/` there are a lot of the following errors:

```
Dec  3 11:19:22 ubuntu kernel: [ 1627.918209] 
ecryptfs_parse_tag_70_packet: Error attempting to find auth tok for fnek sig [1b62c525049b45e0]; rc = [-2]
Dec  3 11:19:22 ubuntu kernel: [ 1627.918214] 
ecryptfs_decode_and_decrypt_filename: Could not parse tag 70 packet from filename; copying through filename as-is`
```

I would really like to either get `ecryptfs` working again properly or to at least recover my data.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I try to use the MOUNT passphrase, I get these errors too (my encrypted home folder was not corrupted):

```
[ 2977.052719] ecryptfs_parse_tag_70_packet: Error attempting to find auth tok for fnek sig [2e1f1a0ca6f5f8f3]; rc = [-2]
[ 2977.052721] ecryptfs_decode_and_decrypt_filename: Could not parse tag 70 packet from filename; copying through filename as-is
[ 2977.052726] Could not find key with description: [2e1f1a0ca6f5f8f3]
[ 2977.052728] process_request_key_err: No key
```

I managed to successfully mount my old home folder simply using the LOGIN passphrase, that is the original password you used when you first created your ecryptfs home folder.

```
host:/mnt/mountpoint/home/.ecryptfs/user> ecryptfs-recover-private .Private
INFO: Found [.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: 
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] 
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: 
Inserted auth tok with sig [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] into the user session keyring
INFO: Success!  Private data mounted read-only at [/tmp/ecryptfs.8dXogIbs].
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What <strike>I did to</strike> created the problem was altering my user password by doing a sudo passwd  which worked fine; but the next day when I tried to login, was then stuck in the gdm login loop.

Then went to the virtual terminal using ctrl-alt-F1, logged in with my new pw, saw that home was empty, did a

```
ecryptfs-recover-private
```

and typed my OLD password. then my home was mounted again and so then could switch back to the graphical interface ctrl-F7 and login with the NEW password :)

Then it was possible to update my cryptfs password on a terminal with:

```
ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```